# Continue after an exception in c#

Tags: c#, exception, web-scraping, try-catch, parallel.foreach

I'm trying to get the doctypes of approx. 3k links. But I get an exception always when it hits the 700-900 mark line.

How can I continue at the point where the exception occurred(so I'm not obliged to start from zero once again)? Is that even possible?

Here is the code that I used:

```
     try
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(linkList, link => 
            {
                stopwatch.Restart();
                Console.Write($"Downloading page {index++} of {linkList.Count}...");
                documents.Add(LoadPage(link));
                Console.Write($" in {stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds} ms");
                Console.WriteLine();
            });

            return documents;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ???
        }
```

Comment: Did you think of moving the try-catch to *inside* the parallel loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the internal code in the try-catch

```
        Parallel.ForEach(linkList, link => 
        {
            try
            {
                stopwatch.Restart();
                Console.Write($"Downloading page {index++} of {linkList.Count}...");
                documents.Add(LoadPage(link));
                Console.Write($" in {stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds} ms");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ???
            }
        });

        return documents;
```

EDIT:

You may also want to look at [thread-safe collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/) that C# has to offer as normal collections are not thread-safe

Answer (score 1):

You would simply need to handle them in the `ForEach`

```
Parallel.ForEach(linkList, link => 
{
    try
    {
       ...
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
        // log
     }
});
```

However you have more issues than this.

1. this looks like IO bound work load, which is not suitable for `Parallel.ForEach`
2. `documents.Add` doesnt look thread safe
3. your index will be out

In all honesty this really looks like a job for *TPL Dataflow*, It gives you the benefit of working well with *async and await* and IO bound work loads. using *async and await*, will stop thrashing the Task Scheduler letting IO completion ports do their job freeing up the threadpool.

It will also allow you to make more complicated pipelines, and be able to re-feed failed jobs back in to it self if you need, and many many other advantages

Comment: actually I tried await with Async  but it didn't worked. Afterwards I tried to split the linkList into smaller lists and tried it again with thread.sleep and await+ async again.. failed once more.

Comment: @Sayit yes this will need to be a strategic change and a small learning curve, but it will work a lot better. however that is deserving of another question. with more information

Answer (score 0):

Okey guys, thats the solution which led me to my goal.

```
        var index = 1;
        Parallel.ForEach(linkList,  link => { GetDocuments(stopwatch, index++, linkList, documents, link); });

        if (FailedDownloads.Count > 0)
        {
            linkList = new List<string>(FailedDownloads);
            FailedDownloads.Clear();
            Parallel.ForEach(linkList,
                link => { GetDocuments(stopwatch, index++, linkList, documents, link); });
        }
        return documents;
    }

    private void GetDocuments(Stopwatch stopwatch, int index, List<string> linkList, List<HtmlDocument> documents, string link)
    {
        stopwatch.Restart();
        Console.Write($"Downloading page {index} of {linkList.Count}...");
        try
        {
            documents.Add(LoadPage(link));
            Console.Write($" in {stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds} ms");
        }
        catch (AggregateException e)
        {
            if (e.InnerExceptions[0] is HttpRequestException)
            {
                FailedDownloads.Add(link);
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```